# convert xpt DateTime into as.POSIX

Tags: r, datetime

I have a xpt data frame that I read into RStudio with a DateTimePOSIX column that looks like this:

```
ID  DateTime
1   2017-01-06T06:02
1   2017-01-30T08:02
2   2017-01-30T15:02
```

How can I convert the `DateTime` column into `DateTimePOSIX`? 
I need the `as.POSIXct` formatted DateTime for further calculations of time differences etc.

Comment: `as.POSIXct(df$DateTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")` ?

Comment: Or, if you wanted `POSIXlt` then you could use `strptime(df$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")`